# Connection string of SQL database with Active Directory using user authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure, active-directory, database-connection

I am connecting to a database on my Azure server where database is on different server and connection I made by choosing option Active Directory with user Credentials option. It is working in SQL server but I need a connection string to connect with DB. Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

If integrated, then use the below connection string:

```
Data Source=xxxxxxx.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;
```

If you're connecting using username and passsword:

```
Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx; Authentication=Active Directory Password; User ID=xxxxxxx; Password=xxxxxxx;
```

Reference:
https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication.md#7-connect-to-your-database-by-using-azure-active-directory-identities

Answer (score 0):

Also you can find the connection string via Azure portal:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help, also if this helpful to you, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited, thanks:)